# Transform-origin for an SVG group in Electron is ignored

Tags: css, svg, electron

I have a simple SVG icon which I animate in CSS. Here is the SVG:

```
<svg width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 512 512" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" className={this.state.isTimewatchActive ? "active" : ""}>
  <rect fill="lightgrey" id="background" ry="20" rx="20" height="512" width="512" y="0" x="0" />
  <g id="icon">
    <path
      d="m352.35001,180.85625l-1.2375,-1.16875l12.65,0l5.84375,5.3625l15.46875,-15.675l-28.05,-27.70625l-15.95,15.33125l6.05,6.325l0,12.7875l-3.4375,-3.23125c-21.51875,-19.45625 -48.125,-31.075 -77.6875,-33.61875l0,-26.2625l-22,0l0,26.125l-1.375,0c-30.04375,2.0625 -58.4375,15.46875 -79.75,36.4375l0,-12.2375l6.11875,-6.325l-15.74375,-15.2625l-28.05,27.6375l15.46875,15.675l5.84375,-5.3625l12.2375,0c-0.20625,0 -0.48125,0.48125 -0.6875,0.75625c-22.55,24.13125 -35.0625,55.61875 -35.0625,88.34375c0,71.775 59.19375,130.2125 132.06875,130.2125c72.7375,0 131.93125,-58.36875 131.93125,-130.14375c0,-32.725 -12.375,-64.00625 -34.65,-88zm-91.85,117.90625l-5.5,12.2375l-5.5,-12.2375c-9.625,-2.40625 -16.5,-10.8625 -16.5,-20.96875c0,-9.4875 7.90625,-17.875 16.5,-20.83125l0,-88.9625l11,0l0,88.89375c9.28125,2.54375 16.5,10.93125 16.5,20.9c0,10.10625 -6.875,18.5625 -16.5,20.96875z"
      fill="#FFFFFF"
      stroke="null"
    />
  </g>
</svg>
```

(I am working in the context of React, so the `className` attribute is really a `class` and the expression is evaluated to output the class string.)

This SVG has two states, active (with `class="active"` on the `svg` tag) and inactive (the code block above).

Here is the (post)CSS for the two states:

```
svg {
    #icon {
        transform: scale(0.8);
        transform-origin: center center;
        transition: all 0.2s;
    }

    #shadow {
        opacity: 0;
        transition: all 0.2s;
    }

    #background {
        transition: all 0.2s;
    }

    &.active {
        #background {
            fill: $greenHn;
        }

        #icon {
            transform: scale(1);
        }

        #shadow {
            opacity: 0.2;
        }
    }
}
```

So at first, the icon should display at scale 0.8 in the center of the background. In Electron, it is scaled down but the transform origin is top left. The weird thing is that if I open the dev tools in Electron and toggle the `transform-origin: center center` rule (with the checkbox in the right-hand side panel), and toggle it back on, the rule is correctly applied.
So it doesn't seem to be a CSS problem but then I don't know what to do.

Does anyone have any idea?

Thanks :)

---

**EDIT**
As I read that SVG isn't supposed to support `transform-origin`, I tried using a `transform: translate()` instead, but I have the same behaviour.

Comment: Should that be `class`, not `className` in your `<svg>` tag?  I'm not familiar with Electron, but I don't see a `className` attribute anywhere in their docs.

Comment: @Paul LeBeau That's specific to Reactjs.

Comment: Sorry, I failed to mention that this was all in the context of React. `className` is just the React way of using the `class` attribute. My class is correctly toggled so I have no problem with that part, I think